# How to prove that $a^x-b^x\leq(a-b)^x$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

It is also known that $a>0$, $b>0$, $a>b$ and $0< x <1$.

Comment: What have you tried (AM-GM, logarithms, derivatives...)? What tools are you supposed to use to solve this inequality?

Answer (score 4):

First set $a=tb$, where $t>1$, and reduce the inequality to
$$
t^x-1\le(t-1)^x
$$
Consider $x$ fixed and $f(t)=t^x-1-(t-1)^x$ defined over $(1,\infty)$. Note that
$$
\lim_{t\to1^+}f(t)=0
$$
and that
$$
f'(t)=xt^{x-1}-x(t-1)^{x-1}=
x\left(\frac{1}{t^{1-x}}-\frac{1}{(t-1)^{1-x}}\right)
$$
Note that $1-x>0$; since $0<t-1<t$, we have $(t-1)^{1-x}<t^{1-x}$. Can you draw a conclusion about the derivative above and so finish up the argument?

Comment: I can't draw a conclusion about the derivative above and so finish up the argument.
I understand that the derivative is supposed to be negative? But what does that imply?
What does the derivative in general imply? That such a function is continuous? But what does that prove me?

Comment: @KristjanKalam You should finish by noting that $f'(t)<0$ for $t>1$, so the function is decreasing. Since $\lim_{t\to1^+}f(t)=0$, this implies that $f(t)<0$ for $t>1$.